# OpenCV C++: implementing Normed Cross Correlation (TM_CCORR_NORMED) without matchTemplate

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to implement TM_CCORR_NORMED by myself. Right now the result resembles OpenCV's matchTemplate CCORR instead. Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

I've been following this (slide 30): [http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture07.pdf](http://www.cse.psu.edu/%7Ertc12/CSE486/lecture07.pdf)

I've tried implementing this without success: https://web.psi.edu/spc_wiki/Normalized%20Cross-Correlation

```
   //Read, template, convert both to gray
   cv::cvtColor(inMat, inMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
   cv::Mat tempMat = cv::imread(file);
   cv::cvtColor(tempMat, tempMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

   //Add padding
   int width = cv::getOptimalDFTSize(std::max(inMat.cols,tempMat.cols));
   int height = cv::getOptimalDFTSize(std::max(inMat.rows,tempMat.rows));

   cv::Mat inFFT, tempFFT;
   cv::copyMakeBorder(inMat, inFFT, 0, height - inMat.rows, 0, width - inMat.cols, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(0));
   cv::copyMakeBorder(tempMat, tempFFT, 0, height - tempMat.rows, 0, width - tempMat.cols, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(0));

   //Convert to CV_32F.
   inFFT.convertTo(inFFT, CV_32F);
   tempFFT.convertTo(tempFFT, CV_32F);

   //Normalize in and temp
   cv::Scalar inMatMean, inMatStdDev;
   cv::meanStdDev(inFFT,inMatMean,inMatStdDev);
   inFFT = (inFFT - inMatMean)/inMatStdDev[0];

   cv::Scalar tempMatMean, tempMatStdDev;
   cv::meanStdDev(tempFFT,tempMatMean,tempMatStdDev);     
   tempFFT = (tempFFT - tempMatMean)/tempMatStdDev[0];


   //Apply FFT
   cv::dft(inFFT,inFFT,0,inMat.rows);
   cv::dft(tempFFT,tempFFT,0,tempMat.rows);

   cv::Mat ccorrFFT, ccorr;

   

   //Cross correlate normalized FFTs
   cv::mulSpectrums(inFFT,tempFFT,ccorrFFT,0,true);

   //IDFT. DFT_SCALE divides result by width*height
   cv::dft(ccorrFFT,ccorr, cv::DFT_SCALE + cv::DFT_INVERSE);

   cv::normalize(ccorr, ccorr, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());  //mais

   //Get max correlation point
   double minVal, maxVal;
   cv::Point minLoc, maxLoc;
   cv::minMaxLoc(ccorr, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);

   //Draw circle, on corr map, around the max point
   cv::circle(ccorr, maxLoc, 10, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3 );

   //Convert corr map to 8UC1
   cv::Mat ccorr8UC1;
   ccorr.convertTo(ccorr8UC1, CV_8UC1);
```

My code:

[image]

TM_CCORR_NORMED with matchTemplate:

[image]

TM_CCORR with matchTemplate:

[image]

Comment: [Go to](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/imgproc/src/opencl/match_template.cl)
find `matchTemplate_CCORR_NORMED`.

 also see [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/170bf6d7af9c8bb2b34ec143826594dc84251b89/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp)


,is this helpful?

Comment: I tried to follow your second link, between lines 819 and 834, and couldn't make It work.